# Discord.Net | Create Webhook

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

Can I create a webhook for some channel using C# `Discord.Net` library?
I tried to google and search in documentation, but couldn't find anything about it. In `Discord.js` there is:

```js
channel.createWebhook({
  name: 'Username',
  avatar: 'link',
}).then(webhook => console.log(`Created webhook ${webhook}`))
```

Does `Discord.Net` have something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here: https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/2658

Shortly:

1. Update to Discord.Net 3.10.0
2. Cast IIntegrationChannel on your channel object.

```cs
var channel = Context.Channel as IIntegrationChannel;
await channel.CreateWebhookAsync("test");
```